# boto EMR add step and auto terminate

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, emr

Python 2.7.12

boto3==1.3.1

How can I add a step to a running EMR cluster *and* have the cluster terminated after the step is complete, regardless of it fails or succeeds?

**Create the cluster**

```
response = client.run_job_flow(
    Name=name,
    LogUri='s3://mybucket/emr/',
    ReleaseLabel='emr-5.9.0',
    Instances={
        'MasterInstanceType': instance_type,
        'SlaveInstanceType': instance_type,
        'InstanceCount': instance_count,
        'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': True,
        'Ec2KeyName': 'KeyPair',
        'EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup': 'sg-1234',
        'EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup': 'sg-1234',
        'Ec2SubnetId': 'subnet-1q234',
    },
    Applications=[
        {'Name': 'Spark'},
        {'Name': 'Hadoop'}
    ],
    BootstrapActions=[
        {
            'Name': 'Install Python packages',
            'ScriptBootstrapAction': {
                'Path': 's3://mybucket/code/spark/bootstrap_spark_cluster.sh'
            }
        }
    ],
    VisibleToAllUsers=True,
    JobFlowRole='EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
    ServiceRole='EMR_DefaultRole',
    Configurations=[
        {
            'Classification': 'spark',
            'Properties': {
                'maximizeResourceAllocation': 'true'
            }
        },
    ],
)
```

**Add a step**

```
response = client.add_job_flow_steps(
    JobFlowId=cluster_id,
    Steps=[
        {
            'Name': 'Run Step',
            'ActionOnFailure': 'TERMINATE_CLUSTER',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Args': [
                    'spark-submit',
                    '--deploy-mode', 'cluster',
                    '--py-files',
                    's3://mybucket/code/spark/spark_udfs.py',
                    's3://mybucket/code/spark/{}'.format(spark_script),
                    '--some-arg'
                ],
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar'
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

This successfully adds a step and runs, however, when the step completes successfully, I would like the cluster to auto-terminate as noted in the AWS CLI: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/create-cluster.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case (creating the cluster using boto3) you can add these flags
`'TerminationProtected': False, 'AutoTerminate': True,` to your cluster creation. In this way after your step finished to run the cluster will be shut-down.

Another solution is to add another step to kill the cluster immediately after the step that you want to run. So basically you need to run this command as step

```
aws emr terminate-clusters --cluster-ids your_cluster_id
```

The tricky part is to retrive the cluster_id.
Here you can find some solution: [Does an EMR master node know it's cluster id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227091/does-an-emr-master-node-know-its-cluster-id)

Comment: Perhaps I have to use suggestion #2, as there does not seem to be an `AutoTerminate` option with boto3. `Unknown parameter in Instances: "AutoTerminate", must be one of: MasterInstanceType, SlaveInstanceType, InstanceCount, InstanceGroups, Ec2KeyName, Placement, KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps, TerminationProtected, HadoopVersion, Ec2SubnetId, EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup, EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup, ServiceAccessSecurityGroup, AdditionalMasterSecurityGroups, AdditionalSlaveSecurityGroups`

Comment: I had the same problem using cloudformation. So I used the option 2, it works quite well. Actually the step that I'm using is calling a lambda function that take care to remove the cloudformation stack (that contains the EMR cluster).

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with option #2.

Comment: With `boto3==1.4.8`, it looks like `AutoTerminate` is set to `True` by default when you call `run_job_flow`. `KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` is the parameter to change this behavior -
 https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.run_job_flow

Comment: @Nobu Is there a way to change the setting for `KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` while the clustering is running? What I mean is set it to be `true` when starting the cluster, then wait and run some steps with conditions, then set the `KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` to be `false`, then add some steps.

Comment: @Nobu thanks man that was super helpful. I had `KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps` set to True and didn't realize it. That's the real solution here... In my opinion this answer has one wrong solution and the second one is more of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

The `'AutoTerminate': True` parameter as suggested did not work for me. However, it worked when I set the parameter `'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps'` from `True` to `False`. Your Code should look then as the following:

```
response = client.run_job_flow(
    Name=name,
    LogUri='s3://mybucket/emr/',
    ReleaseLabel='emr-5.9.0',
    Instances={
        'MasterInstanceType': instance_type,
        'SlaveInstanceType': instance_type,
        'InstanceCount': instance_count,
        'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': False,
        'Ec2KeyName': 'KeyPair',
        'EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup': 'sg-1234',
        'EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup': 'sg-1234',
        'Ec2SubnetId': 'subnet-1q234',
    },
    Applications=[
        {'Name': 'Spark'},
        {'Name': 'Hadoop'}
    ],
    BootstrapActions=[
        {
            'Name': 'Install Python packages',
            'ScriptBootstrapAction': {
                'Path': 's3://mybucket/code/spark/bootstrap_spark_cluster.sh'
            }
        }
    ],
    VisibleToAllUsers=True,
    JobFlowRole='EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
    ServiceRole='EMR_DefaultRole',
    Configurations=[
        {
            'Classification': 'spark',
            'Properties': {
                'maximizeResourceAllocation': 'true'
            }
        },
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a short-lived cluster that automatically terminates after all steps have been run by specifying 'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': False in the Instances param. I've added a complete example to [GitHub](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/904ccdab93220d59eb45bdc9c299288036406e5d/python/example_code/emr/emr_usage_demo.py#L345) that shows how to do this.

Here's some of the code from the demo:

```
def run_job_flow(
        name, log_uri, keep_alive, applications, job_flow_role, service_role,
        security_groups, steps, emr_client):
    try:
        response = emr_client.run_job_flow(
            Name=name,
            LogUri=log_uri,
            ReleaseLabel='emr-5.30.1',
            Instances={
                'MasterInstanceType': 'm5.xlarge',
                'SlaveInstanceType': 'm5.xlarge',
                'InstanceCount': 3,
                'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': keep_alive,
                'EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup': security_groups['manager'].id,
                'EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup': security_groups['worker'].id,
            },
            Steps=[{
                'Name': step['name'],
                'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
                'HadoopJarStep': {
                    'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                    'Args': ['spark-submit', '--deploy-mode', 'cluster',
                             step['script_uri'], *step['script_args']]
                }
            } for step in steps],
            Applications=[{
                'Name': app
            } for app in applications],
            JobFlowRole=job_flow_role.name,
            ServiceRole=service_role.name,
            EbsRootVolumeSize=10,
            VisibleToAllUsers=True
        )
        cluster_id = response['JobFlowId']
        logger.info("Created cluster %s.", cluster_id)
    except ClientError:
        logger.exception("Couldn't create cluster.")
        raise
    else:
        return cluster_id
```

And here's some code that calls this function with some real params:

```
output_prefix = 'pi-calc-output'
pi_step = {
    'name': 'estimate-pi-step',
    'script_uri': f's3://{bucket_name}/{script_key}',
    'script_args':
        ['--partitions', '3', '--output_uri',
        f's3://{bucket_name}/{output_prefix}']
}
cluster_id = emr_basics.run_job_flow(
    f'{prefix}-cluster', f's3://{bucket_name}/logs',
    False, ['Hadoop', 'Hive', 'Spark'], job_flow_role, service_role,
    security_groups, [pi_step], emr_client)
```